# Question about limit sup and inf

Tags: real-analysis

Let ${x_n}$ be defined by

$$x_n : = \begin{cases} \frac{n+1}{n}, &\text{if } n \text{ is odd}\\
0,&\text{if } n \text{ is even}.
\end{cases}$$

I am pretty sure about $\lim_{n\to\infty}\inf x_n =  0$

because if ${x_1} = 2$, $x_2 = 0$, $x_3 = 4/3$, $x_4 = 0$   so $\lim_{n->\infty}\inf x_n = 0$

But about sup

$$\sup\{x_k : k \geq n\}=\begin{cases}
\frac{n+1}{n},   &\text{if } n \text{ is odd}\\
\frac{n+2}{n+1}, &\text{if } n \text{ is even}.
\end{cases}$$

I understand about odd but don't understand about when $n$ is even.

Why it is not $0$ when $n$ is even?

Comment: I would prefer to rewrite $x_n = \begin{cases} 1+ \frac{1}{n}, & n \, \textrm{odd} \\ 0, & n \, \textrm{even} \end{cases}$

Comment: yeah I don't know what latex is for that .

Answer (score 1):

When $n$ is even, $n+1$ is odd. What is the value of $x_{n+1}$? Is there are ny $x_k$ with $k>n$ and such that $x_k>x_{n+1}$?

Comment: ah I just got it when n = 2 the set ${x_k : k \geq 2}$ gonna be $x_2 = 0, x_ 3 = 4/3  = \frac{2n+1}{n+1}$

Comment: so in this case sup gonna be $\frac {2n+1}{n+1}$ 
Is this right logic?

Comment: It will be $\frac{n+2}{n+1}$. I believe you mistyped that.

Comment: oh yeah I mistype :/

Answer (score 1):

The $\limsup$ of a sequence (when it exists) is defined as the smallest number $X$ such that, for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $N_{\epsilon}$ such that, for all $n>N_{\epsilon}$, $x_n < X+\epsilon$. Since there are always terms greater than $1$, no matter how far you go, the $\limsup$ of your sequence cannot be $0$.

Comment: Yeah I know about that sup cannot be zero, but I did not know that why n is even $\frac{n+2}{n+1}$

Answer (score 1):

You can use the highest exponent limit identity which would get you both limits = 1 on both even and odd cases.

Then, since k is only an index, the limit of the $x_k$s would be the same as the limits of the sequence of $x_n$s, which would be 1. So, the $\sup$ of the set will be $1$, too.